# Run define from message passing

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (memoize message f)
  (define (dispatch message)
    (cond 
     ((eq? message 'm) k)
     ((eq? message 'um) 20)))

  (define (k) 
    (let ((table (make-table)))
      (lambda (x)
        (let ((previously-computed-result (lookup x table)))
          (or previously-computed-result
              (let ((result (f x)))
                (insert! x result table)
                result)
              )))))
  f)

(set! fib(memoize 'm fib))
```

My idea is that I am sending m, as the message, then the  ((eq? message 'm) k) will check true so define k will run and change the fib because of set!, but the code does not work as I expect it to work, could someone help me out please

Comment: Where do you call `dispatch`?

Comment: You need to call `k` as `(k)` to return its nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `dispatch` and return the result. You're just returning the same function you were called with.

And in `dispatch` you need to call `k`, not just return it, since it returns the closure that has the lookup table.

```
(define (memoize message f)
  (define (dispatch message)
    (cond 
     ((eq? message 'm) (k))
     ((eq? message 'um) 20)))

  (define (k) 
    (let ((table (make-table)))
      (lambda (x)
        (let ((previously-computed-result (lookup x table)))
          (or previously-computed-result
              (let ((result (f x)))
                (insert! x result table)
                result)
              )))))
  (dispatch message))
```

Comment: I appreciate you so much, thank you mate, tried to figure it out for hours now, thank you

Comment: If i want to unmemoris, is there a way to do so, or should I just write the whole original function again and call it?

Comment: You would need `memoize` to return multiple functions, or a function that takes an operation code.